# Android - Lat long values are 0.0 and 0.0

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am trying to fetch my device's location for an application. The code returns 0.0 for latitude and longitude. What do I need to change? Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post this question without another sentence. Hopefully, this much text is enough.

```
//Getting the location
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(location !=null){
                    plat = location.getLatitude();
                    plong = location.getLongitude();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        };
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
        Log.d("lat: ",Double.toString(plat));
        Log.d("long: ",Double.toString(plong));
```

Answer (score 1):

RequestLocationUpdates is asynchronous-  it takes time.  The value of plat and plong will not be ready until onLocationChanged is called.  SO you can't use them until then.

Answer (score 0):

move

```
Log.d("lat: ",Double.toString(plat));
Log.d("long: ",Double.toString(plong));
```

to

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

and make sure that GPS is enabled

Comment: Thank you Gabe and Muhannad. I moved the Log.d inside onLocationChange and they show the correct Lat and Long. 

When I later use plat and plong to store the data in strings and push to my server, I typically get 0.0. Only once did I get the right values.

@Gabe: This is my first time doing this. What do I need to do fetch the data correctly?

Comment: can you post the code that you are using to send this data + when are you calling this code ?